# GCE Third Party for automation (snapshots/images etc...)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disaster-recovery

I am new to `Google Compute Engine` and I want to do automatic images/snapshot backups every X hours.

Previously I have used Amazon Cloud (EC2 instances) and did the automatic backups with a third party tool called Skeddly (which is UI that by setting some fields, it makes an automation for this backups).

Now, I would like to find a third party tool that will do something similar in GCE instance.

I know that it is possible to do with gcloud commands, or powershell, but I would like to do it with UI (third party tool) if exists.

What could you recommend me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to vote on https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using directly the SDK, by running gcloud commands with Cron but if you want to use external tools I'll recommend you to use Terraform or Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud now provides dedicated service for [backup and disaster recovery](https://cloud.google.com/backup-disaster-recovery).

> Backup and DR allows you to protect virtual copies of your data in its native format, manage these copies throughout their lifecycle, and use these copies for disaster recovery, business continuity, and development and test activity.

[Here is the official quickstart tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/backup-disaster-recovery/docs/quickstarts/gce-instances-backup-recovery) which shows how to protect and recover compute engine instance.